# How can I make the button below disabled until all the above section has at least clicked one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

my code:

```
<div class="tables">
<form>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
      <tr>
    <th class="thheader">Monday</th>
    <th class="thheader">Tuesday</th>
    <th class="thheader">Wednesday</th>
    <th class="thheader">Thursday</th>
    <th class="thheader">Friday</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>

      </td>
      <td>
      <center>
      <input type="checkbox" class="colour-button" value="10 - 12" id="btn1012" /><label for="btn1012">10am - 12pm</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="colour-button" value="10 - 12" id="btn1214" /><label for="btn1214" class="labe"> 5pm - 7pm</label>
      </center>
      </td>
      <td>


      </td>
            <td>
            <center>
      <input type="checkbox" class="colour-button" value="10 - 12" id="btn10" /><label for="btn10">10am - 12pm</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="colour-button" value="10 - 12" id="btn12" /><label for="btn12" class="labe">  5pm - 7pm</label>
      </center>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>


</div>
</center>
<center>
<input type="checkbox" class="colour-button1" value="10 - 12" id="btn1" /><label for="btn1">Thursday, March 2nd</label>
<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="colour-button1" value="10 - 12" id="btn2" /><label for="btn2" class="labe1">Tuesday, March 7th</label>
<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="colour-button1" value="10 - 12" id="btn3" /><label for="btn3">Thursday, March 16th</label>
<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="colour-button1" value="10 - 12" id="btn4" /><label for="btn4" class="labe1">Tuesday, March 21st</label>

</center>
<center>
<button  class="disabled white cbtn1 c1" type="submit" id="submit" value="NEXT">NEXT<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</center>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
      enable_cb();
      $(".colour-button").click(enable_cb);
    });

    function enable_cb() {
      if (this.checked) {
        $("input.colour-button1").removeAttr("disabled");
      } else {
        $("input.colour-button1").attr("disabled", true);
      }
    }

</script>
```

CSS:

```
.colour-button {
  display: none;
}
label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.colour-button + label {
  background:  #c1c1c1;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.colour-button:checked + label {
  background: #cf5630;
}
.thheader{
    width:135px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#FAFAFA;
    color: #18181d;
}
.tables{
    width:800px;
}
.labe{
    padding:5px 18px !important;
}
.colour-button1 {
  display: none;
}
.colour-button1 + label {
  background:  #c1c1c1;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 18px 200px;
}
.colour-button1:checked + label {
  background: #cf5630;
}
.labe1{
    padding:18px 207px !important;
}
.cbtn1.disabled {
 background-color: #c1c1c1;
width:150px;
padding:1em;
border-radius:3px;
border:none;
margin:3em auto;
padding-left:35px;
display:inline;
margin-left:30px;
}
```

I want it that after I have chosen at least one from each section, to become enabled and be orange, and clickable. How is this possible since it is a button not an input? as you can see I have a javascript for already to make the second section not active if the first isn't chosen yet.

Comment: `How is this possible since it is a button not an input?` You know buttons can be disabled too, right?

Comment: Yes But I have never implemented it using a button thats why Im unsure on how to do it, any ideas? @Fissio

Comment: The same way you would do it on an input, basically - select the button and remove the `disabled` attribute.

Comment: Wait I did something like this and it didnt seem to work:
`var checkBoxes = $('.colour-button1');
 checkBoxes.change(function () {
     if (!checkBoxes.filter(':checked').length < 1) {
         $('#submit').prop({disabled: false}).removeClass('disabled').addClass('orangeBtn');
       }
       else {
         $('#submit').prop({disabled: true}).addClass('disabled').removeClass('orangeBtn');
       }
 });
 checkBoxes.change();`

Comment: The `<center>` tag has been depricated you should not use this anymore [Readmore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) You could simply add a class="center" to each element where it is needed and add this code in your CSS  .center{text-align:center;} Your Markup has other errors as well `</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using jQuery you can disable/enable Buttons (and other fields) with the following snippet.

```
$('#buttonID').prop("disabled", true);
```

Overall your question was not very clear to me. There are a lot of ways to accomplish what you want. For example you can use listeners or onClick events.

Here is a small fiddle (made more or less from your code) that activates a button if you select at least one date checkbox and one time checkbox:  https://jsfiddle.net/3fc30k5s/

good luck :)